Searching input of table's items messing with table's pagination
I have a table  that divides the its items per 20 lines and, above the table, a searching input to filter items that matches the written words. Both the tools works ok alone. I can navigate through the pages when there are more than 20 items and i can find the items when i type it in the inut.
The problem is: everytime i have more than one page i try to search something, the item appears in the first page and if i am in the second page i can see nothing unless i go back to the first page.
I think that the correct thing to do is to decrease the number of pages to matche the quantity of items that i found, but i don't know how to do it.
You can take a look in the page and the code below:

The code:
    const [currentPage, setcurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const itemsPerPage = 15;

    // Calculo dos índices para exibir os itens da página atual
    const indexOfLastItem = currentPage * itemsPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstItem = indexOfLastItem - itemsPerPage;
    // const currentItems = produtos.slice(indexOfFirstItem, indexOfLastItem);

    const totalPages = Math.ceil(produtos.length / itemsPerPage);

    const changePage = (newPage) => {
        if(showDetalhes === true){
        setShowDetalhes(false);
        }
        setcurrentPage(newPage);
    };
    

    //jsx return
    <table className="table" id='table-estoque'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" id="titulo-tabela-padrao">Categoria</th>
                            <th scope="col" id="titulo-tabela-padrao">Código</th>
                            <th scope="col" id="titulo-tabela-padrao" style={{ width: '40%' }}>Produto</th>
                            <th scope="col" id="titulo-tabela-padrao">Preço</th>
                            <th scope="col" id="titulo-tabela-padrao">Preço Promocional</th>
                            <th scope="col" id="titulo-tabela-padrao" style={{width:'2%', color:'#FFEA00'}}><i className="fa-solid fa-pen fa-sm"></i></th>
                            <th scope="col" id="titulo-tabela-padrao" style={{width:'2%', color:'#eb2632'}}><i className="fa-solid fa-trash fa-sm"></i></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        {produtos
                            .filter((item) => {
                                // return search.toLowerCase() === '' || item.pro_descricao.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()); //se digitar algo aparece na lista
                                const searchWords = search.toLowerCase().split(' '); //atribui à searchWirds tudo que foi digitado dividido por space                        
                                return searchWords.every((word) => //faz a busca para cada palavra digitada mesmo que fora de sequencia
                                item.pro_descricao.toLowerCase().includes(word)
                                ); 
                            })
                            .slice(indexOfFirstItem, indexOfLastItem) //Mudei a logica para paginacao para antes do map e nao la em cima como antes 
                            .map((produto, index) => (
                                <React.Fragment key={index}>
                                <tr>
                                    <td className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'td-item-par' : 'td-item-impar'} id="item-tabela-padrao">{produto.cat_descricao}</td>
                                    <td className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'td-item-par' : 'td-item-impar'} id="item-tabela-padrao">{produto.pro_codigo}</td>
                                    <td className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'td-item-par' : 'td-item-impar'} id="item-tabela-padrao">{produto.pro_descricao}</td>
                                    <td className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'td-item-par' : 'td-item-impar'} id="item-tabela-padrao">{new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', {minimumFractionDigits: 2,maximumFractionDigits: 2}).format(produto.pro_preco1)}</td>
                                    {produto.pro_preco_promocao > 0 ? <td className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'td-item-par' : 'td-item-impar'} id="item-tabela-padrao">{new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', {minimumFractionDigits: 2,maximumFractionDigits: 2}).format(produto.pro_preco_promocao)}</td>
                                    :
                                    <td className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'td-item-par' : 'td-item-impar'} id="item-tabela-padrao">--</td>                                      
                                    }
                                    <td  className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'td-item-par' : 'td-item-impar'} id="item-tabela-padrao"><div id="a-editar" onClick={(e) => OpenModalProduto(produto.pro_id)} ><i className="fa-solid fa-pen fa-sm"></i></div></td>
                                    <td  className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'td-item-par' : 'td-item-impar'} id="item-tabela-padrao"><div id="a-excluir" onClick={(e) => confirmarExclusao(produto.pro_id)}><i className="fa-solid fa-trash fa-sm"></i></div></td>
                                </tr>
                                {showDetalhes && detalhesIndex === index && (
                                <tr>
                                    <td  className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'td-item-par' : 'td-item-impar'} colSpan="12" style={{ borderBottom: '1px solid #000' }}>
                                    <div style={{ padding: '15px' }}>
                                        {
                                            jsonOpcionais?.map(item => {
                                                return <div className='row' key={item.poi_id}>
                                                        <div className='col-1 ms-auto me-3'>
                                                        {item.status === 'N' ? <span id='status-itens-op' className='badge bg-secondary ms-2'>Inativo</span> : <span id='status-itens-op' className='badge bg-success ms-2'>Ativo</span>}
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div className='col-4'>
                                                        <span>{item.poi_descricao}</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div className='col-1 me-auto'>
                                                        {item.poi_valor === 0 ? <span id='span-zero'>{new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', {style: 'currency', currency:'BRL'}).format(item.poi_valor)} </span> : <span id='span-maior-zero' key={index}>{new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', {style: 'currency', currency:'BRL'}).format(item.poi_valor)} </span>}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                            })
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                )}
                            </React.Fragment>
                            ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                {totalPages > 1 && (
                    <div className="pagination">
                        <button className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm ms-auto" onClick={() => changePage(currentPage - 1)} disabled={currentPage === 1}> Anterior</button>
                            <span className="span-pagina ms-1 me-1 ">Página {currentPage} / {totalPages}</span>
                        <button className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onClick={() => changePage(currentPage + 1)} disabled={currentPage === totalPages}>Próxima</button>
                    </div>
                )}


I would suggest you update the pagination logic to reflect the number of filtered items and possibly reset the current page to 1 whenever a new search is performed if that works though

@GifftyCode Now i got the first part of ur suggestion:
totalPages = Math.ceil(filteredProdutos.length / 15);
but when i try to setcurrentPage(1) i get 'too many re-renders' error...

i found a way:
function Produtos() {
// Calculo dos índices para exibir os itens da página atual
const indexOfLastItem = currentPage * itemsPerPage;
const indexOfFirstItem = indexOfLastItem - itemsPerPage;
// const currentItems = produtos.slice(indexOfFirstItem, indexOfLastItem);

let totalPages = Math.ceil(produtos.length / itemsPerPage);

const changePage = (newPage) => {
    if(showDetalhes === true){
    setShowDetalhes(false);
    }
    setcurrentPage(newPage);
};

useEffect(() => {
    setcurrentPage(1);
},[search]);


return <>
<Navbar tela='cardapio'/> 
        
<ProdutoModal isOpen={isProdutoOpen}
              onRequestClose={CloseModalProduto}
              categorias={categorias}
              dadosProduto={dadosProduto}
              onClickSalvar={ListarCardapio}
/>

<ProdutoOpcionalModal isOpen={isOpcionalOpen}
                      onRequestClose={CloseModalOpcional}
                      id_pro={id_pro}
                      pro_descricao={pro_descricao}
/>
<LoadingScreen isLoading={isLoading} />

<div className='container-fluid corpo-pagina'>

    <div className="d-flex table-buttons mt-4">
        <button id='style-outline-button' onClick={() => OpenModalProduto(0)} className='btn ms-2' >
            <i className='fas fa-plus'></i>Adicionar Produto
        </button>
        <button onClick={exportToExcel} className="button-exportar">Exportar</button>

        <div className="box-input">
            <i className="fa fa-search fa-sm" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <input onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Localizar" id="input-localizar-intern"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div className='m-2 mt-4'>
        {(() => {
            const filteredProdutos = produtos.filter((item) => {
                const searchWords = search.toLowerCase().split(' ');
                return searchWords.every((word) => item.pro_descricao.toLowerCase().includes(word));
            });

            totalPages = Math.ceil(filteredProdutos.length / 15);

            return (
                <>
                    <table className="table" id='table-estoque'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col" id="titulo-tabela-padrao">Categoria</th>
                                <th scope="col" id="titulo-tabela-padrao">Código</th>
                                <th scope="col" id="titulo-tabela-padrao" style={{ width: '40%' }}>Produto</th>
                                <th scope="col" id="titulo-tabela-padrao">Preço</th>
                                <th scope="col" id="titulo-tabela-padrao">Preço Promocional</th>
                                <th scope="col" id="titulo-tabela-padrao" style={{width:'2%', color:'#FFEA00'}}>
                                    <i className="fa-solid fa-pen fa-sm"></i>
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col" id="titulo-tabela-padrao" style={{width:'2%', color:'#eb2632'}}>
                                    <i className="fa-solid fa-trash fa-sm"></i>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {filteredProdutos
                                .slice(indexOfFirstItem, indexOfLastItem)
                                .map((produto, index) => (
                                    <React.Fragment key={index}>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'td-item-par' : 'td-item-impar'} id="item-tabela-padrao">{produto.cat_descricao}</td>
                                            <td className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'td-item-par' : 'td-item-impar'} id="item-tabela-padrao">{produto.pro_codigo}</td>
                                            <td className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'td-item-par' : 'td-item-impar'} id="item-tabela-padrao">{produto.pro_descricao}</td>
                                            <td className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'td-item-par' : 'td-item-impar'} id="item-tabela-padrao">{new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', {minimumFractionDigits: 2,maximumFractionDigits: 2}).format(produto.pro_preco1)}</td>
                                            {produto.pro_preco_promocao > 0 ? <td className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'td-item-par' : 'td-item-impar'} id="item-tabela-padrao">{new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', {minimumFractionDigits: 2,maximumFractionDigits: 2}).format(produto.pro_preco_promocao)}</td>
                                            :
                                            <td className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'td-item-par' : 'td-item-impar'} id="item-tabela-padrao">--</td>                                      
                                            }
                                            <td className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'td-item-par' : 'td-item-impar'} id="item-tabela-padrao">
                                                <div id="a-editar" onClick={() => OpenModalProduto(produto.pro_id)} >
                                                    <i className="fa-solid fa-pen fa-sm"></i>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'td-item-par' : 'td-item-impar'} id="item-tabela-padrao">
                                                <div id="a-excluir" onClick={() => confirmarExclusao(produto.pro_id)}>
                                                    <i className="fa-solid fa-trash fa-sm"></i>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        {showDetalhes && detalhesIndex === index && (
                                        <tr>
                                            <td className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'td-item-par' : 'td-item-impar'} colSpan="12" style={{ borderBottom: '1px solid #000' }}>
                                                <div style={{ padding: '15px' }}>
                                                    {jsonOpcionais?.map(item => (
                                                        <div className='row' key={item.poi_id}>
                                                            <div className='col-1 ms-auto me-3'>
                                                                {item.status === 'N' ? <span id='status-itens-op' className='badge bg-secondary ms-2'>Inativo</span> : <span id='status-itens-op' className='badge bg-success ms-2'>Ativo</span>}
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div className='col-4'>
                                                                <span>{item.poi_descricao}</span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div className='col-1 me-auto'>
                                                                {item.poi_valor === 0 ? <span id='span-zero'>{new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', {style: 'currency', currency:'BRL'}).format(item.poi_valor)} </span> : <span id='span-maior-zero' key={index}>{new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', {style: 'currency', currency:'BRL'}).format(item.poi_valor)} </span>}
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    ))}
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        )}
                                    </React.Fragment>
                                ))}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    {totalPages > 1 && (
                        <div className="pagination">
                            <button className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm ms-auto" onClick={() => changePage(currentPage - 1)} disabled={currentPage === 1}> Anterior</button>
                            <span className="span-pagina ms-1 me-1 ">Página {currentPage} / {totalPages}</span>
                            <button className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onClick={() => changePage(currentPage + 1)} disabled={currentPage === totalPages}>Próxima</button>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </>
            );
        })()}
    </div>
</div>

Set current page as 1 everytime i type in search input and                 totalPages = Math.ceil(filteredProdutos.length / 15);
after filtering

//replace this
const totalPages = Math.ceil(produtos.length / itemsPerPage); 

//new code
 const totalPages = Math.ceil(
    produtos.filter((item) => {
      // return search.toLowerCase() === '' || item.pro_descricao.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()); //se digitar algo aparece na lista
      const searchWords = search.toLowerCase().split(" "); //atribui à searchWirds tudo que foi digitado dividido por space
      return searchWords.every(
        (
          word //faz a busca para cada palavra digitada mesmo que fora de sequencia
        ) => item.pro_descricao.toLowerCase().includes(word)
      );
    }).length / itemsPerPage
  );

secondly try to keep this in parent and pass it as props to table component
const [currentPage, setcurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const itemsPerPage = 15;

    // Calculo dos índices para exibir os itens da página atual
    const indexOfLastItem = currentPage * itemsPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstItem = indexOfLastItem - itemsPerPage;
    // const currentItems = produtos.slice(indexOfFirstItem, indexOfLastItem);

    const totalPages = Math.ceil(produtos.length / itemsPerPage);

and i assume the onChange function of search field is something like this
const handleChange=(e)=>{
   setSearch(e.target.value);
   //add this line below
   setcurrentPage(1)   
}

